# Flutter, vertical align column on page for a ListView->Column widget tree

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I have a Flutter look like the following. Which show a CircularProgressIndicator when the page first load.

It aligns with top of the page. But how can I vertical center the CircularProgressIndicator on the page?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      controller: _scrollController,
      children: [_buildArticleList()],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildArticleList() {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: _orderListStream,
        builder: (context, snap) {
          if (snap.data != null) {
            List<Widget> children = [];

            ...
            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: children,
            );
          } else {

            return Column(
              
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [CircularProgressIndicator()],
            );
       ;
          }
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wrap the `CircularProgressIndicator` with a `Column` widget, just wrap it with a `Center` widget.

Check the example code below:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      controller: _scrollController,
      children: [_buildArticleList()],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildArticleList() {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: _orderListStream,
        builder: (context, snap) {
          if (snap.data != null) {
            List<Widget> children = [];

            ...
            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: children,
            );
          } else {

            return  
              Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
             ),
            );
       ;
          }
        });
  }
```